# What is an alternative to oil in layered paratha?

Tags: oil

When cooking layered paratha, what can I use as an alternative to oil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Butter or ghee](http://www.bawarchi.com/recipe/ghee-paratha-oetr5kidhcgac.html). In fact, I prefer it.

Comment: Might be worth noting that you can get vegetarian or even vegan ghee, if that might be a consideration for some people.

Comment: ... joke, right?

Comment: No, deadly serious. Most 'Indian' restaurants in the UK use it - it's also ***way*** cheaper than the real thing. £2.50/kg rather than £10. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghee

Comment: Yes, but vegan ghee is basically oil.  See question.